# Problems modifying comment highlight in coffee.vim

Tags: javascript, vim, coffeescript

I'm trying to modify the highlight of CoffeeScript comments:

```
"" coffeescript comments
syntax keyword coffeescriptCommentTodo    TODO FIXME XXX TBD contained
syntax region  coffeescriptLineComment    start=/####\@!/ end=/###/ keepend contains=coffeescriptCommentTodo,@Spell
syntax region  coffeescriptEnvComment     start=/####\@!/ end=/###/ display
syntax region  coffeescriptLineComment    start=/####\@!/ end=/###/ keepend contains=coffeescriptCommentTodo,@Spell fold
syntax region  coffeescriptCvsTag         start="\$\cid:" end="\$" oneline contained
syntax region  coffeescriptComment        start=/#*/      end="\$" contains=coffeescriptCommentTodo,coffeescriptCvsTag,@Spell fold
```

I admit I'm doing it a bit randomly, basing myself in this other syntax file:

```
syn match coffeeComment /#.*/ contains=@Spell,coffeeTodo
hi def link coffeeComment Comment

syn region coffeeBlockComment start=/####\@!/ end=/###/
\                             contains=@Spell,coffeeTodo
hi def link coffeeBlockComment coffeeComment

" A comment in a heregex
syn region coffeeHeregexComment start=/#/ end=/\ze\/\/\/\|$/ contained
\                               contains=@Spell,coffeeTodo
hi def link coffeeHeregexComment coffeeComment
```

With that I have now (the first code), everything looks commented except if statements. How do I modify the syntax file to highlight properly CoffeeScript comments?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doing a search for `#*` matches the whole of any file, because the `*` matches any number of the preceding character even zero. So all characters match zero `#`s.

That's why the example you posted uses `#.*` -- match one `#` then any number of any character (`.*`)

I've found this to be a useful reference: [VimRegex](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).

The offending line is:

```
syntax region  coffeescriptComment        start=/#*/      end="\$" contains=coffeescriptCommentTodo,coffeescriptCvsTag,@Spell fold
```

Try: `start=/#\+/` to match at least one `#` and any more.